# How to configure ADFS 2.0 as SP and CA SiteMinder as IdP

Tags: adfs2.0

We want to configure ADFS 2.0 as SP and CA SiteMinder as IdP using SAML 2.0. In ADFS 2.0 we have a test application which is deployed using WIF.

We have configured both the things correctly. However, while testing the federation it gives 2 options of selecting the Identity provider correctly. However, after we enter the credentials we get internal server error as message.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Thanks,
Pravin

Comment: Hi Pravin,

I'm trying to do the same thing but wihtout any success.  Were you able to figure out how to do this?  Do you mind to share your findings.  

I'm also looking at using SM FSS as STS provider for WIF claim-based applications.

Thai

Comment: Hi Thai,
I am not able to get any success yet. I can definitely share my findings but after I am done with all the configurations.

Pravin

Answer (score 1):

There's [this guide](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff754295(WS.10).aspx) available on Technet that you might find useful.